# How can we determine if we are running in EC2 or Fargate?

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-fargate

I have a Java service running tasks on both AWS EC2 and Fargate. Is there a way to determine if we are running in EC2 or Fargate programatically by using the AWS libraries or otherwise ?

Comment: I asked AWS this question at training last week. AWS said under Fargate, there is an environment variable set. I don't remember the name. Maybe that clue will help.

Comment: @JohnHanley I recently looked for something like this in Fargate, in the environment, and didn't see it. Anyway it should be easy enough to see the env, just override entrypoint with `printenv` and check the log.

Comment: Before posting my hint, I did a Google search and could not find the variable name. A quick Python program can get you the environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The environment variable is AWS_EXECUTION_ENV. Its value is AWS_ECS_EC2 for EC2 and AWS_ECS_FARGATE for Fargate. This is available with fargate platform >= 1.3.0

Comment: Where is this documented?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can do it using the `describeTasks` method in the [AWSECSClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ecs/AmazonECSClient.html) class. The Launch Type is going to be either EC2 or Fargate.

You can use this in conjunction with the [metadata endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint.html) to introspect your own taskArn, then match up the ARN with the response from `describeTasks` to determine the Launch Type.

Answer (score 0):

You can always test which metadata endpoint works. ECS Task metadata endpoint vs ec2 endpoint.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-metadata-endpoint.html

vs

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/util/EC2MetadataUtils.html